# action of $O(n,\mathbb{R})$ on $S^n$

Tags: topological-groups

I need to know what is the action of $O(n,\mathbb{R})$ on $S^n$,  and $O(n,\mathbb{R})/O(n-1,\mathbb{R})\cong S^{n-1}$, how does $O(n-1,\mathbb{R})$ sit inside $O(n,\mathbb{R})$?

The obvious action may be $\phi:O(n,\mathbb{R})\times S^n\rightarrow S^n:(A,x)\mapsto Ax$?

Comment: Fix a point of $S^n$ and consider its stabilizer.

Comment: thank you, got it, $\{A\in O(n,\mathbb{R}):Ax=x\}$

Comment: All your $S^n$'s should be $S^{n-1}$'s, by the way: $O(n)$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and the unit sphere is $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: Do you need more clarifications here?

Comment: no thank you [][][][]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the action is $(A,x) \mapsto Ax$.

Now fix $x_0 \in S^{n-1}$. Verify that the closed subgroup $G = \{A \in O(n) \mid A x_0 = x_0\}$ fixes the hyperplane $(x_0)^{\perp}$ and that it can be identified with $O(n-1)$. For example, if you take $x_0 = (0,\dots,0,1)$ then $G$ consists of the matrices of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
B & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \in O(n), \quad B \in O(n-1).
$$
The to see that $f \colon O(n)/G \to S^{n-1}$ is a homeomorphism, observe that it is a continuous bijection since $O(n)$ acts transitively, then use that a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism.

Comment: could you please explain how the transitive action of $O(n)$ says that is a continous bijection?please

Comment: If $G$ acts on a set $S$ and $H$ is the stabilizer of $s \in S$ then $G/H$ is in bijection with the orbit $Gs$ (this is just algebra). In particular, if $G$ acts transitively on $S$ then $G/H$ is in bijection with $Gs = S$. That the map is continuous follows from the definition of the quotient topology.